# Mysterious Brazilian jungle plant

Tags: identification, tropical

A couple of years ago a guy claimed to have brought a Brazilian plant from the jungle. He wanted to bring a banana but as soon as the plant grew it was obvious that this was no banana plant.

If you water it properly (meaning really a lot!) it grows superfast and if you take a dead part of the "root" and put it in soil it starts growing again.

The plant grows like a banana, the "branch" creates a leaf, it unfolds and then the branch keeps growing until there is a new leaf which unfolds...

Because it was supposed to be a banana and is growing amazingly fast, we called it "bananorris".

**The thing is: I have this plant for about eight years now but I couldn't figure out what kind of plant it is.**

Does anybody recognize it?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks exactly like ginger, though exactly WHICH ginger is going to have to await flowering.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zingiberales

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginger

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedychium_coronarium

The flowering types I grow appear to be in a different sub-family than the common ingredient in commerce. They smell quite possible when repotting, but I have not tried eating them nor seen a definitive yes/no answer on that.

Comment: Ginger?? Wtf... Hm, when does it usually start growing flowers? This one is about 1-2 years I guess.

Comment: Are there non-consumable ginger types?

Comment: Mine went 16 years in poor light without flowering, then flowered happily when moved to better light. Recent additions put in better light to begin with took a year or two. I have two cultivars that look like this - white ginger and kahili ginger - as far as I know "yellow" ginger should look about the same (plant-wise) and is the usual one in commerce. I don't know if others are considered inferior or or somehow inedible. I also have something called "blue ginger" which is a whole different family - related to wandering jew, not a "true ginger" at all, looks quite different.

Comment: Seems to be a science for itself :) Thx for solving my mystery after all these years!